Swift A script of macOS is not running on the M2 chip?
I am making a macOS app using SwiftUI, app is working fine on mac Intel chip, mac Apple M1 chip but not working on the mac M2 chip.
Below is the following code which is crashing on M2 chip for force unwrapping the data in String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8).
I know that force unwrap is not suitable, but for testing purpose I am doing force unwrap.
When I run the which ffmpeg in terminal it provides the path in result, no matter which mac terminal is (it always return actual path of ffmpeg), but when run this command from the swift Program it does not found anything and got crashed on apple M2 chip.
My actual scenario (or requirement) is I need to get the path using the command which ffmpeg and write that path in the file on macOS app.
Kindly guide me why the code is crashing or not providing the actual path.
func findFFmpegPath() -> String? {
            let task = Process()
            task.launchPath = "/bin/bash" // Path to bash shell
            task.arguments = ["-l", "-c", "which ffmpeg"] // Execute "which ffmpeg" command
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe // Capture any errors as well

    do {
        try task.run()
        let data = try pipe.fileHandleForReading.readToEnd()
        let output = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print("data:\(data)\n\(output)\n\(output?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))")
        return output?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    } catch {
        print("Error running task: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}

When I run which ffmpeg in the terminal it gives me path correctly, See the screenshot bleow.

When I run the /bin/bash -l -c "which ffmpeg" in the M2 than I got this result.

When I run the /bin/bash -l -c "which ffmpeg" in the Apple M1 than I got this result.

Getting desired result in the terminal, but not getting result from the Swift Program.

Can you run the task in the terminal with the expected output?

Yes I am able to run the task with the expected output.

@Jens Peter I added the screenshot of terminal in the question.

Try task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh" and /bin/bash -l -c "which ffmpeg" in the Terminal.

@Willeke I tried the command as you suggested in the terminal, I added the screenshot of terminal in the questions.

Similar issue: NSTask not picking up $PATH from the user's environment
